# Cannot retrieve data from firebase '400 Bad Request'

Tags: python, php, firebase, webcam, popen

I trying to retrieve data from firebase but it give me this error

Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `GET https://linkfirebase.firebasedatabase.app/GSBACILLI5%0A` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response.

the reference is GSBACILLI5, but why the path to request data is GSBACILLI5%0A?

Btw, GSBACILLI5 is decode from QR code using webcam in python, did it give any problem to the path?

This is my code to call python program in PHP

```
$commandString = "python trackqr3.py";
                            $outpy=popen($commandString, 'r');
                            $contents = '';
                            #while (!feof($outpy)) {
                            foreach ((array)$outpy as $outpy){
                                $contents .= fread($outpy, 8192);
                                
                                
                            }
```

And this is my python script

```
import cv2

def capture():
    
    # initialize the cv2 QRCode detector
    detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()

    while True:
        _, img = cap.read()
        # detect and decode
        data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
    # check if there is a QRCode in the image
        if data:
            a=data
            print(a)
            return a
            #break
            

        cv2.imshow("QRCODEscanner", img)   
        #if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        #    break
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)  
id=capture()
cap.release()
#print('ID:',id)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: `%0A` means `new line` (`Enter`). `ord('\n')` gives value `10` which in hex is `0A` (`hex(ord("\n"))`. You have to remove new line from string - in Python you can use `strip()` for this.. Or if you send it as `print()` then use `end=""` - `print(...., end="")` - because `print()` automatically add new line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`%0A` means `new line` (`Enter`). Code `hex(ord("\n"))` gives `0A`.

You send reference using `print()` but `print()` automatically add `new line` at the end of string.

You have to use `end=""` to skip new line

```
print(a, end="")
```

OR in PHP you should remove/strip this new line.
But I don't remeber what function in PHP it needs.